# Replace named group in regex match

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have the following regular expression:

```
pattern = '^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*_(?P<pos>[A-Z]\d\d)_T\d{4}(?P<fID>F\d{3})L\d{2}A\d{2}(?P<zID>Z\d{2})(?P<cID>C\d{2})\.tif$'
```

that matches file names like these:

```
filename = '151006_655866_Z01_T0001F015L01A02Z01C03.tif'
```

with groups:

```
m = re.match(pattern, filename)
print m.group("pos")  # Z01
print m.group("fID")  # F015
print m.group("zID")  # Z01
```

**How can I replace only a specified group with a given string in Python?**

I tried to use `re.sub` with a function call, but don't know how this function should look like:

```
def replace_function(matchobj):
    # how to replace only a given match group?
    # (the following replaces *all* occurrences of "Z01" in this example)
    return matchobj.group(0).replace(matchobj.group("slice"), "---")

print re.sub(pattern, replace_function, filename)
```

My desired result would be:

```
151006_655866_Z01_T0001F015L01A02---C03.tif
```

Comment: The `repl` argument to `re.sub` should, if callable, take a single match object and return a string to replace that match in the original. Your match contains multiple parts of the same string, so isn't really appropriate for this usage - try just capturing the part you want to replace.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I thought of that, but my idea was to have the pattern configurable (i.e. an input that is just required to contain several named groups), so I hoped for a way to just replace that specific group, or at least retrieve its position within the target string. But as you suggest, I guess I need to parse the pattern to modify it to capture only the required part.

Comment: @JanEglinger if the proposed solution works as expected please accept the answer. If it is not, explain why or better provide a failing test, i'll try to fix the code as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you need using a closure and the start/end index of the chosen matching group:

```
import re
from functools import partial

pattern = '^[\w-]*_(?P<pos>[A-Z]\d{2})_T\d{4}(?P<fID>F\d{3})L\d{2}A\d{2}(?P<zID>Z\d{2})(?P<cID>C\d{2})\.tif$'
filename = '151006_655866_Z01_T0001F015L01A02Z01C03.tif'


def replace_closure(subgroup, replacement, m):
    if m.group(subgroup) not in [None, '']:
        start = m.start(subgroup)
        end = m.end(subgroup)
        return m.group()[:start] + replacement + m.group()[end:]

subgroup_list = ['pos', 'fID', 'zID', 'cID']
replacement = '---'

for subgroup in subgroup_list:
    print re.sub(pattern, partial(replace_closure, subgroup, replacement), filename)
```

**Output**:

```
151006_655866_---_T0001F015L01A02Z01C03.tif
151006_655866_Z01_T0001---L01A02Z01C03.tif
151006_655866_Z01_T0001F015L01A02---C03.tif
151006_655866_Z01_T0001F015L01A02Z01---.tif
```

An online implementation is available [here](http://ideone.com/hmPZMW)

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks for introducing me to [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: @JanEglinger you're welcome! Note that the use of *partial* is not mandatory (you can simply define an equivalent piece of code as stated in the docs) but help to keep the code cleaner. I've also slightly reduced the regex pattern (mainly ``[a-zA-Z0-9_] -> \w``, just cosmetic not a fix)

Answer (score 3):

To get the desired output just capture begin and end of what to
preserve. Insert the `---` between it.

Find `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*_[A-Z]\d\d_T\d{4}F\d{3}L\d{2}A\d{2})Z\d{2}(C\d{2}\.tif)$`
Replace:  `$1---$2`